# Open branch.io link in same app

Tags: android, android-intent, branch.io

I try to open a new activity with a branch.io link in current opened app. 
The following code works. The problem here is that the browser is opened and this call the new activity.

```
Intent actionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://sample.test-app.link/foo"));
startActivity(actionIntent);
```

I know that the the browser visit the website of branch.io, get the data and call a other link like `intent://....`. I'm searching a way to get the intent-link (`intent://`) from the web-link (`https`).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to enable `App links` and add the SHA256 Fingerprint in link settings.

In your app you should set a new intent filter for get the http requests to.

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="xxxx.test-app.link" />
</intent-filter>
```

Now your app receive and handle the links, the browser will not opened.

The steps are described [in the docs](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/guide/android/).

Answer (score 1):

The Branch SDK is not designed to facilitate routing back into an app from the app's own webview. That said, it sounds like you have gotten something working and that is fantastic.

Concerning the easiest way to grab the Intent string created from a Branch link: on a device that has the app installed, paste the Branch link into the Chrome address bar and hit enter. The intent string will appear both in the address bar and in the error that will appear on the resulting web page.

Retrieving the intent string in this fashion works because Chrome does not support opening apps by entering an intent string into the address bar like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think You can achieve it by below steps:

In the manifest file under activity's intent filter put:

```
  <data android:host="example.com" android:scheme="http" ></data>
```

Now your clickable link should be like :

http://example.com/tutor/

In activity you can right the code to make any condition based on URL

```
Uri data = getIntent().getData();
    if(data!=null) {
        List<String> params = data.getPathSegments();
        String first = params.get(0); // "status"
        String second = params.get(1);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for help! You are right, this should work, but I need some solution with [branch.io](https://branch.io/). I have found a solution now ;-)